# No JTA UserTransaction available - specify either 'userTransaction' or 'userTransactionName' in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, weblogic, jta

I am getting the following stack trace while running my application in tomcat 7. Same application is working fine in Weblogic AS.

```
15:31:48.896 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - No JTA UserTransaction found at default JNDI location [java:comp/UserTransaction]
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.TransactionFactory.getObjectInstance(TransactionFactory.java:116) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.findUserTransaction(JtaTransactionManager.java:653) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.initUserTransactionAndTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:447) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JtaTransactionManager.java:414) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:143) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:381) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:539) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
15:31:48.896 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/TransactionManager]
15:31:48.896 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - No JTA TransactionManager found at fallback JNDI location [java:comp/TransactionManager]
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [TransactionManager] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [TransactionManager].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.findTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:687) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.initUserTransactionAndTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:453) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JtaTransactionManager.java:414) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:143) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:381) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:539) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
15:31:48.896 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:appserver/TransactionManager]
15:31:48.896 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - No JTA TransactionManager found at fallback JNDI location [java:appserver/TransactionManager]
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [appserver/TransactionManager] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [appserver].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178) ~[spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.findTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:687) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.initUserTransactionAndTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:453) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JtaTransactionManager.java:414) [spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:143) [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:381) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:539) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 does not provide any transaction manager like WebLogic does.
You need to deploy a product like JOTM to do so.

Comment: By defining a Spring transaction manager in your bean xml configuration file you can solve the issue. org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager. Plus add datasource in context.xml file

Answer (score 0):

My problem fixed after adding my datasource in tomcat context.xml file as a Resource like below.